# Codename one - How to integrate ZXing source lib into my project so i not need to install ZXING App

Tags: codenameone

I have developing a simple android application then scan qr code and return a text to my form.

but when i invoke scanner method i have asked to install zxing app

How to integrate ZXing source lib into my  project so i not need to install ZXING App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with a way of doing it natively on Android although I'm sure it's possible. However, there is a zlib library that is embeddable and works better in some regards.

It's available here: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner